# Wifi won't turn on during startup after upgrading from kernel 3.2 to 3.5, 3.8 and etc

Tags: wireless, kernel

I use an Acer 4750 laptop, which has a bcm43225 wifi chip.
In Ubuntu 12.04, each time I boot up, my laptop's wifi will automatically turn on, and the 12.04 use kernel 3.2
However, when I upgraded to 12.10, 13.04, using a newer kernel, 
I found my wifi not automatically turning on during startup.
But its function is normal:I still can turn on it with Fn key.

I have experimented it, using a 3.9 kernel in Ubuntu 12.04, it was the same situation, won't turn on during boot but can be switch on with Fn key.

I have checked the rfkill list, no device was blocked

So, how do I make my wifi automatically turn on with newer kernel?
It will be more convenient for me~~

Ps:I'm using bcmwl-kernel-source

Answer (score 1):

Try this commands in terminal. 
`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`
`sudo modprobe wl`

Answer (score 0):

Try these

`sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

`sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

From this threaed --> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1997880.
I skipped the first command and still worked.

This works for me.